# How to update grunt devDependencies?

Tags: node.js, gruntjs, npm

I am relatively new to grunt and am not really familiar with node yet.

I have a boilerplate **Gruntfile** and **package.json** file that I use in all my projects and modify it as needed.

When I start each project I want to update all the Grunt plugins in devDependencies and the package.json, but I don't know of a quick and easy way to do this.

Is it possible to update all modules with one command or do I have to do them individually?

Thanks.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

In your `package.json` you can tag each dependency with a range of versions to install then type `npm install` to install all the listed dependencies at the given versions:

**Only install `0.6.0`:**

```
{
  "devDependencies": {
    "grunt-contrib-watch": "0.6.0"
  }
}
```

**Prefix with `~` to install the latest *patch* version `0.6.x`:**
As `0.6.1`, `0.6.2`, `0.6.3`, etc versions are released, `npm install` will install the latest version of those. If `0.7.0` is release, it will not install that version (generally a good strategy as it may contain breaking changes).

```
{
  "devDependencies": {
    "grunt-contrib-watch": "~0.6.0"
  }
}
```

**Explicitly set the range:**
You can use `>`, `<`, `<=`, `>=` to explicitly set the version range. Another good option for custom ranges or if you would like to be explicit with your version ranges. The follow will install every version greater or equal than `0.6.0` but less than `1.0.0`:

```
{
  "devDependencies": {
    "grunt-contrib-watch": ">= 0.6.0 < 1.0.0"
  }
}
```

**Always install the latest with `*`**
Or if you just always want the latest version use `*`:

```
{
  "devDependencies": {
    "grunt-contrib-watch": "*"
  }
}
```

See more about version ranges in the npm docs: https://www.npmjs.org/doc/misc/semver.html

---

**`npm outdated`**
If you would like to see which of your dependencies are out of date, use `npm outdated`: https://www.npmjs.org/doc/cli/npm-outdated.html

---

**`npm update`**
Use `npm update` to update all your dependencies to the latest versions. Or `npm update packagename anotherpackage` to update specific packages to the latest version.

Comment: I was unaware of the "*" nomenclature. That solved the problem. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

### 1. Сhoice

[**grunt-dev-update**](https://www.npmjs.com/package/grunt-dev-update) plugin — is my choice.

---

### 2. Relevance

This answer is relevant for February 2018. In the future, the data from this answer may be obsolete.

Author of this answer personally used this plugin at February 2018.

---

### 3. Argumentation

See [**plugin description**](https://www.npmjs.com/package/grunt-dev-update):

> Why not use `npm update` or `npm install`?
>
> first — `npm update` doesn't work on dev dependencies,
> second — `npm update` stays inside your semver matching in your `package.json`,
> thirdly — npm isn't automated like your grunt tasks.

---

### 4. Usage

Installation, usage instructions and options are described in [**official plugin description**](https://www.npmjs.com/package/grunt-dev-update).

---

### 5. option.semver

Strange option name; I did not understand at first, what is `options.semver`.

Example configuration:

```markdown
Package name    : autoprefixer
Package type    : devDependencies
Current version : 6.7.7
Wanted version  : 6.7.7
Latest version  : 8.0.0

Package name    : browser-sync
Package type    : devDependencies
Current version : 2.23.5
Wanted version  : 2.23.6
Latest version  : 2.23.6
```

You run `grunt devUpdate` in console:

**If** `semver: true`:

autoprefixer not update, browser-sync update.

**elif** `semver: false`:

autoprefixer **and** browser-sync update both.